# How to load mdbootstrap vue into Laravel 5 with laravel-mix?

Tags: laravel, installation, mdbootstrap

I am trying to install mdbootstrap vue into a Laravel 5.6 project, but i realy don't understand how i suppose to do it.

If somebody can give me a little tutorial, it would be nice of you ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this(updated)...

(Assuming you have already installed laravel)

Go to your project directory and do:

`npm install --save mdbvue`

You will also need:

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2`

next go to `resources/js/bootstrap.js` and under the `require('bootstrap');` add `require('mdbvue');` it should look something like this:

```
/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
    require('mdbvue'); //<---this is what you need to add
} catch (e) {}
```

Next go to `resources/sass/app.scss` and add the MDB css under the bootstrap import, you might also need to import the font-awesome css:

```
// Material Design Bootstrap
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "~mdbvue/build/css/mdb.css";
```

Now to compile your `app.css` and `app.js` files just do `npm run dev`

With this everything should be up and running and you are free to use `MDBvue` components or simply use `MDB` jQuery version.

This worked for me on a Laravel 5.7 project. Hope this helps.

Comment: on the side: if you're like me, coming from "we, the JS framework, will do all the scaffolding for you" world and new to laravel: make sure you add styles and scripts to blade templates!

`<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/scripts.js') }}"></script>`

BTW, currently I am registering components one-per-one basis, in `resources/js/app.js`, like so:
`Vue.component('mdb-input', require('mdbvue/src/components/Input'));`
Isn't there a more elegant, less repetive way?

Great answer, @natral!

Comment: If you are trying to compile SASS, then in `/resources/sass/app.scss` why not use SASS instead of CSS? @import "~mdbvue/build/scss/mdb"

Comment: Did you find a more elegant way to register all of the components at once, @JakubStrebeyko? I know just enough about vue to wonder if it's me or the mdbvue package that's giving me fits. :/

Comment: >Everything that is mentioned in the best answer is correct, but doing tests in a view of functions js are not enabled while not exporting jquery and mdb in the view in my case in the file home.blade.php
```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
``` >I hope someone will give you this information

Comment: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js)